# Simulate a comma / dot keypress

Tags: c++, keyboard, simulation

With the header cctype I can simulate key presses in c++ :

```
void keyDownZ()
{
    keyboardInput.ki.wVk = 0x05A;
    keyboardInput.ki.dwFlags = KEYDOWN;
    SendInput(1, &keyboardInput, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

But I can't find anywhere on how to simulate the keypress of the comma key, or the dot key.. What is the hexidecimal code for those keys?

Answer (score 1):

I mean, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
 VK_OEM_COMMA ( 0xBC )
```

> Virtual-Key Codes The following table shows the symbolic constant
>   names, hexadecimal values, and mouse or keyboard equivalents for the
>   virtual-key codes used by the system. The codes are listed in numeric
>   order.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this ones:

```
HTML Entity (decimal)   &#44;  
HTML Entity (hex)   &#x2c;
UTF-8 (hex)     0x2C (2c)  
UTF-8 (binary)  00101100  
UTF-16 (hex)    0x002C (002c)  
UTF-16 (decimal)    44  
UTF-32 (hex)    0x0000002C (2c)  
UTF-32 (decimal)    44  
C/C++/Java source code  "\u002C"  
Python source code  u"\u002C"
```

I think this is what you need:
    **UTF-8 (hex)   0x2C (2c)**

Comment: hmm when using 0x2C as value for ki.wVk it doesn't type anything :(

Answer (score 0):

There are [2 values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
VK_OEM_COMMA  0xBC
VK_OEM_PERIOD 0xBE
```

According to [this thread](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?275945-Virtual-Key-Code-for-VK_DECIMAL), you can also test `VK_DELETE`.

Comment: I have tried all the given codes, but they all just will not work. Could it be my laptop or .. ?